# Fetching data in react component, all components ends up with the same data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to render a react component which is populated by data from a fetch-request to my backend API, but when i add multiple components, all components end up with the data from the last request.

I use redux and react, along with flow. I'm successful in fetching the information from my backend-server and I have made sure that i receive the expected information. I am able to set the information in the component once the state changes, but all components end up with the same information. Here is my code:

My action:

```
export function fetchStates(order_id) {
  return dispatch => api.post(`${order_id}/states`)
      .then((response) => {
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_STATES_SUCCESS', response });
       });
}
```

code from my component-file:

```
type Props = {
  states: Array<State>,
  order_id: number,
  fetchStates: () => void,
}
//... and then inside the component
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchStates(this.props.order_id)  
}
// This function is called from the render() method
renderStates() {
  return this.props.states.map((state) =>
    <div style={{ flex: '1' }}>
      {state.name}     
    </div>
  );
}
// Connecting the component
export default connect(
  state => ({
    states: state.states.states,
  }),
  { fetchStates }
)(States);
```

And my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  states: [],
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {    
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'FETCH_STATES_SUCCESS':
        return {
            ...state,
            states: action.response.data,
        };
    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

And to create the components i use:

```
<States order_id={ order.id }/>
```

Expected results:

```
Component 1: state1, state2, state3 (from fetch 1)
Component 2: state4, state5, state6 (from fetch 2)
Component 3: state7, state8, state9 (from fetch 3)
```

Actual results:

```
Component 1: state7, state8, state9 (from fetch 3)
Component 2: state7, state8, state9 (from fetch 3)
Component 3: state7, state8, state9 (from fetch 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly new to react and redux as well but believe I see the problem in your renderStates method.

```
renderStates() {   return this.props.states.map((state) =>
    <div style={{ flex: '1' }}>
      {state.name}     
    </div>   ); }
```

You do not assign a unique key to each div created so react is unable to update each one individually causing all to be updated when the state changes, resulting in the last update (state7, state8, state9) to show in all components.

I believe the fix would be along these lines:

```
renderStates() {   return this.props.states.map((state) =>
    <div key={state.id} style={{ flex: '1' }}>
      {state.name}     
    </div>   ); }
```

The key (no pun intended) is providing a value that will be unique to each state to the key property. That may be an id field if it exists in your case, name.ToString() or some other value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however this did not help. The accessible id's in renderStates, it either 7, 8 or 9. I tried adding the key to the parent "order" as well, but it did not work either.

Comment: Thinking through how the code would execute it seems to me like you are expecting states in your store to be [fetch1.data, fetch2.data, fetch3.data]? But it seems to me that it would just be [fetch3.data] because of the way you are using the spread operator. As the calls are made with fetchStates the store value for states would be set to [fetch1.data] then [fetch2.data] then [fetch3.data] which is mapped in each of your components causing them all to be the same.